# Remove overlaps and no data areas from GeoTIFF display in Global Mapper

Tags: convert, display, global-mapper

I have two GeoTIFF files that are in UTM projection. I am opening them in Global Mapper v17 and they are displaying like this:

[image]

My issue is that the "black" areas (which I presume are areas where there is no data) overlap other tiles that do have data. I thought maybe it was something to do with the UTM projection, but when I convert it to Geographic projection (which is ultimately what I want to do) the same thing happens:

[image]

I have looked through all the file opening, projection and configuration options in Global Mapper but there doesn't seem like there's an option to hide these black areas to prevent overlaps. If there is such an option, it's not immediately apparent to me.

Is there a way to hide these black areas? Even better, is there a way to "clip" these black areas so that when I convert the projection to Geographic, if I then export the files to new GeoTIFFs I'll get perfectly rectangular images with no black areas?

Comment: Is there a NoData value set for the rasters? You can verify with GDALInfo https://gdal.org/programs/gdalinfo.html  If the NoData value is not set or set incorrectly a utility like GDAL_Edit https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_edit.html will let you set the NoData value for your images then they should display as you expect. There might be a simple way to do this in Global Mapper, unfortunately I do not know Global Mapper well enough to venture an opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK after a lot of messing around I figured it out. First select all layers you wish to remove the background from and hit the Options button:

[image]

In the popup that comes up, hit the "Set Transparent Color..." button:

[image]

In the popup that comes up, select the background colour you wish to hide (black in my case) and hit OK:

[image]

You'll be sent back to this previous popup. Now check the "Transparent" tick box and hit Apply, wait for it to process, then hit OK:

[image]

Et voila! No more black background and the tiles merge seamlessly with no overlapping :)

[image]

Hopefully this process is similar in other GIS software so that this answer helps out someone else.

Comment: Many thanks for providing an answer to remove the background color in GeoTIFF.
It really helped me.
Thanks once again.